# AEM/CQ: Checkbox is checked saves a Boolean value of TRUE,How to save a Boolean value as FALSE if we Unchecked?

Tags: checkbox, boolean, selection, aem

For Example,I have created a check box with below properties

```
<checkbox1
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    checked="false"
                    defaultValue="false"
                    fieldLabel="Sample"
                    inputValue="true"
                    name="./sample"
                    checkboxBoolTypeHint="{Boolean}true"
                    type="checkbox"
                    xtype="selection">
                    <listeners
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        check="function(isChecked){var panel = this.findParentByType('panel'); var fields = panel.find('name', './sample'); for (var i=0;i&lt;fields.length; i++) {if (fields[i].xtype == 'hidden') { if (isChecked.checked) {fields[i].setDisabled(true);} else {fields[i].setDisabled(false);}}}}"/>

</checkbox1>
<hiddenCheckbox1
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    disabled="{Boolean}true"
                    ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                    name="./sample"
                    value="{Boolean}false"
                    xtype="hidden"/>
```

If we checked/enabled the check box it is showing the  property "Sample" like below
    **sample   Boolean     true**  (working fine)
If we Unchecked/disable the checkbox then it is not showing the property "Sample"

Expectation: I want to show  **Sample  Boolean  false** if we Unchecked/disable the checkbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to check the documentation of the *Sling POST Servlet*. This servlet is called when you submit your dialog. It has something called *Suffixes* which you can use in your dialog to give the POST servlet some hints about what your fields are doing.

One such suffix for example is the `@UseDefaultWhenMissing` suffix, which should be exactly what you are looking for.

From the documentation:

> As described above, @DefaultValue only takes effect if no value is provided for a particular parameter. However, in some cases, such as HTML checkboxes, this isn't sufficient because the parameter isn't submitted at all. To handle this scenario, you can use the @UseDefaultWhenMissing suffixed parameter.

```
<form method="POST" action="/content/page/first" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="queryIgnoreNoise" class="input" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="queryIgnoreNoise@DefaultValue" value="false"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="queryIgnoreNoise@UseDefaultWhenMissing" value="true"/>
</form>
```

So what you have to do in your dialog definition is to add two additional hidden fields:

```
<checkbox1DefaultValue
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    name="./sample@DefaultValue"
    value="{Boolean}false"
    xtype="hidden"/>
<checkbox1UseDefaultWhenMissing
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    name="./sample@UseDefaultWhenMissing"
    value="{Boolean}true"
    xtype="hidden"/>
```

Pay close attention to the names of the fields:

`./sample@DefaultValue` and `./sample@UseDefaultWhenMissing`.

It is the name of the checkbox (`sample`) plus the name of the two required suffixes: `@DefaultValue` and `@UseDefaultWhenMissing`.

There are a few more nice suffixes you can read about in the Sling documentation:

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html

Comment: Thank you so much!.it is  working by creating two hidden fields by using DefaultValue and UseDefaultWhenMissing suffixes.